Jupyterlab widgets do not work, resulting in "Loading widgets..." text
I have Python=3.10.8, jupyterlab=4.2.4, jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.11, ipywidgets=8.1.3
Importing basic ipywidgets
import ipywidgets as widgets
slider = widgets.IntSlider(value=5, min=0, max=10, step=1)
slider

results in Loading widget... text and no widget. I have found this thread by googling and it seems to conclude that

The message is not informative
Widgets "do not seem to be supported" on jupyter-lab

So, if widgets are not supported, what is the point of jupyterlab-widgets library? It clearly states that it enables support for widgets in jupyter-lab.
There is another thread dealing with exactly this issue. However, it has not seen much updates since the last 4 years, and many replies there state that the default solution has been outdated. Among others, this reply states that manually enabling extensions should no longer be necessary, and simply installing the ipywidgets library should be sufficient, which does not seem to work, at least in my case.
Does anybody know the current state of widgets in jupyter-lab?
Edit1: Official page provides a jupyter-lab embedding where widgets work out of the box when installing ipywidgets. So I must be doing something wrong, but what?
Edit2: Problem does not seem to be there on a fresh install with just these 4 libraries. Is some other library interfering with ipywidgets?
Edit3: The problem seems to be gone by itself. I switched to a fresh environment, where it worked. Then I switched back to my original environment, and it started working there too. I guess it was a caching error after all.

You aren't reading some of the documentation you link to or noting dates. One such case is that you link to here where it says jupyterlab_widgets is for JupyterLab 3. You are on JupyterLab 4. You just need ipywidgets and and clean install and a full refresh/reset. You refer to something from 2019 and draw bullet points on current tech. (jupyterlab=4.2.4 is very new.) 2019 was five years ago.

You only need three of those and ipywidgets will then work in modern JupyterLab. (Get jupyterlab_widgets out of any of this.) However, maybe not that JupyterLab with that exact Python. You should pick a more tested set. The release notes of the Anaconda Distribution, here, can help guiding when you are unfamiliar. Look for where it says For a list of all packages included in the installer, to look in more detail.

"So I must be doing something wrong, but what?"  "Problem does not seem to be there on a fresh install with just these 4 libraries. Is some other library interfering with ipywidgets?" Please take some time to troubleshoot this more. You are adding edits that answer your previous question in turn. Edit 1 answers most if what you asked before and then Edit 2 answers your question of "So I must be doing something wrong, but what?" The problem is you aren't starting clean and didn't clean things up first. And so yes, something is interfering. You should also be very careful to refresh your ...

 browser page after every attempt. I advise shutting down everything, Jupyter, browser, computer, and then restarting. And then do a hard refresh on your browser page after you restart everything. (On a Mac with Chrome, this is SHIFT+Command+R).  And then only have all that, try ipywidgets. Trying a different, fresh browser can often help, too.
